# xamarin forms iphone app launches with default blue screen and then jumps to background. No compiler or launch errors

Tags: ios, forms, xamarin, visual-studio-mac

The Xamarin Forms app I'm developing compiles and launches without errors on an iPhone, but simply shows the launch screen for a second or two and then goes to the background.  It doesn't crash. This does not happen on an iPhone 5S, but anything newer such as an iPhone 8S or X this behavior is consistent.   There are no problems with the Android version of the app.   I'm using Visual Studio 2019 for Mac.  Everything is up to date, including Xamarin forms and all of the nuget packages that I'm using.  I can only test on physical devices because there is Bluetooth built into the the app. Any ideas or clues?

Comment: Review the device's console/log: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/debugging-in-xamarin-ios?tabs=windows#accessing-the-console

Comment: it seems likely that those devices are running different versions of iOS, and therefore have different permissions requirements that may be interfering with the launch.

Comment: They are running different Versions of iOS.   Version 10.3 on the 5s and 13 on the 8 and x.   I checked the file Entitlements.plist file and I don't have any permissions required.   Is that the correct place to check the permissions for the iOS app?

Comment: Is there any error message when you debug on your phone?  Check the [device log](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/enhanced-device-logging-in-visual-studio/);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that all I needed to do was Enable "Background Mode" and then "Bluetooth LE Communication" from within Info.plist.   I didn't suspect this since the app functioned properly with iOS 10.x and the symptom didn't lead me to think that bluetooth was the root cause of the problem.  Seems obvious to me now.

Answer (score 0):

try to build a sample app and run it in iOS...
if everything works fine then try to add the packages and run it...
my guess is that you have installed a plugin but failed to initialise it...

Comment: Thanks for the input.   I added all of the packages to my sample app and the sample app works fine. So I think everything is initialized ok.  Any other ideas?